# Diplay a PDF with ActiveStorage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am trying to display a PDF file uploaded via ActiveStorage but I am failing to do so.

The PDF file is correctly uploaded because if I write in my view: `<%= @paper.paper_pdf %>`, I can see the object `#<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f9a7d320400>`

**show.html.erb**

```
    <strong>The PDF of the Paper</strong>
    <br>
    <%= image_tag @paper.paper_pdf %>
    <br>
    <%= @paper.paper_pdf %>
```

What is displayed is the following:

[image: What is displayed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. I had to restart the server.

I hope my silly mistake is going to be useful for someone else.